# How to change the order of properties in SharePoint Modern Document Library in Details Pane?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience

Is it possible to update the order of the properties in detail pane of SharePoint Modern Document Library?

Find below reference:

[image]

I can re-order the columns in Views, but I want same order of columns into Detail Pane also.

How can I achieve that?

Any reference link will be most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design the order of columns in details pane is same as the column order in Content Type.

So, If you want to change the column order in details pane then you need to change the column order in Content type.

[How to change the order of columns in a SharePoint list or library](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-change-the-order-of-columns-in-a-sharepoint-list-or-library/).

**Note**: It will also change the column order in SharePoint list/library default forms as well.

Comment: Thanks, it worked like you said. But at my live environment, same steps is not working.. Any possible reason?

Comment: Welcome. I tried both on developer subscription and production environment. it is working for me. Can you please check again. Are there multiple content types on list/library? If Yes, you need to change the order for all content types.

Comment: Might be permission issue. Because I am not able to access to the parent content type page. So for now this answered my question. I am closing this thread. Will open a new thread if I found something strange. Thank you again for being so real quick.

Comment: Welcome. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Open your list, check the box on a row of data, choose edit.  When the details pane opens there should be a menu item at the top called Edit Form.  then you can drag and drop items up and down the list or uncheck items you don't want to show.